# Corregir error de tarjeta de producto en HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

Muy buen día, el día de hoy vengo en búsqueda de ayuda con un problema que tengo al momento de diseñar mi pagina web respecto al hecho que uno de mis elementos no se muestra correctamente y quisiera pedir su consejo.

Tengo un problema que hace que mis tarjetas de productos se vean así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo quiero que estén solo dentro de mi `container` o de mi `section`.

Dejo el código del `CSS` y el `HTML`

```
<section id="VENTAS">
    <div class="content">
       <article>
                <h3>Productos a la venta<h3>
                <div class="PRODUCTOS">
                    <div class="row center x-s">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="imagenes/logitech_tecladdo.jpg">
                            <h2>Teclado Logitech</h2>
                            <p class="Precio"> 500 $</p>
                            <button> Agregar al carrito</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="imagenes/ilustrracion1.jpg">
                            <h2>IMAGEN 3 JSJSJSJ</h2>
                            <p class="Precio"> 250 pesos</p>
                            <button> Agregar al carrito</button>
                        </div>
        </article>
    <div>
</section>
```

Codigo del `CSS`

```
.card{
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.content{
    padding: 40px;
    background: white;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.content input{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.ventas{

}
```

Agradeceré de todo corazón cualquier ayuda, espero y tengan un excelente día.

Comment: Apelando al poder de la identación, se puede evidenciar que no estás cerrando los `div` con clase **PRODUCTOS** y **row center x-s**. Prueba cerrando apropiadamente ambos `div` y luego nos cuentas si con esto se soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Como no conozco por completo tu código asumo que el problema es no resetear la propiedad **float** por lo que intenta resetear el float en **row center x-s**

```
.row.center.x-s {
     float: none;
     clear: both;
}
```

También trata de crear un div separador para evitar que float o cualquier div mal cerrado afecte la estructura.

```
.separador {
     width: 100%;
     float: none;
     clear: both;
     height: 1px;
}
```

Agregar `<div class="separador"></div>` al final del div PRODUCTOS